# How to limit Java scope to child classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, scope

So, I'm trying to make a variable that can only be accessed directly by its declaring class and its child classes. I was under the impression that `protected` was the scope modifier for that, but I've just (re)discovered it also allows classes in the same package direct access.
Is there a scope modifier that does what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a scope modifier that does what I'm looking for?

[No, there is not.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) The only two scopes which allow access in child classes are `public` and `protected`. It makes reasonable sense that there is no such modifier, since you can't control who can and cannot extend your class: either everyone who can see the class can extend it, or no-one can (because the class is `final`).

Comment: Is there any way to go about doing what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Don't worry so much about access modifiers. They're a helpful hint to readers and consumers of your code, not ironclad security. `protected` should be fine.

Comment: @Matt Ball, exactly since they can be bypassed by reflection anyway.

Comment: Just don't put any other classes in the package with the parent!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill that's a rather silly "solution." Nothing stops someone _else_ from creating a class in the same package. I've actually used that technique to access `protected` classes/fields in third-party libraries (which neatly avoids reflection).

Comment: @MattBall: It's [not true that "nothing" stops that.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html)

Comment: @LouisWasserman good point, that's a feature I frequently forget.

Comment: @MattBall I hate doing this so long after you answered, but thank you for your answer. I wasn't worried so much about other people's code as the project itself is open source, I was just favoring good practice. That seems like a moot point thanks to the nature of Java though. Since that's what I'm looking for, I think I'll go with Ernest's suggestion. Thanks everybody for the input!